# How compare dates that are equal when one has time as well

Tags: sql, oracle, time

I'm trying to compare dates and it looks like I'm doing it like examples online, but I only see the rows of dates returned when I do >= for the comparison.  When I just use = it doesn't return anything.

This is my query with >= for the date comparison:

```
select * 
from valhist_tbl --dmh
where 
CRTUPDDT >=  to_date('28-10-21','DD-MM-YY')
and metricvalue  <> 'Device Found'
order by CRTUPDDT asc
```

I see a lot of this sort of thing returned:

```
CRTUPDDT                          METRICVALUE
28-OCT-21 12.00.00.069000000 AM   NOT FOUND
28-OCT-21 12.00.00.071000000 AM   NOT FOUND
...
```

I want it to do this: CRTUPDDT =  to_date('28-10-21','DD-MM-YY')
but that doesn't return any rows.

I think the comparison as equals and not greater than has to do with the what is returned, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Also, I don't want to see duplicate lines returned, but there's so many that *distinct* makes it take forever.

This is a link I was looking at: [date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972250/how-to-compare-date-in-oracle)

Comment: Try using `trunc` on that column that way it will exclude the time part of the date . like `trunc(CRTUPDDT)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing with date in Oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970277/comparing-with-date-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare on a range over the entire day:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   valhist_tbl --dmh
WHERE  CRTUPDDT >=  DATE '2021-10-28'
AND    CRTUPDDT <   DATE '2021-10-28' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    metricvalue  <> 'Device Found'
ORDER BY CRTUPDDT asc
```

You could also compare using `TRUNC`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   valhist_tbl --dmh
WHERE  TRUNC(CRTUPDDT) =  DATE '2021-10-28'
AND    metricvalue  <> 'Device Found'
ORDER BY CRTUPDDT asc
```

However, if you have an index on `CRTUPDDT` then it would not be used in this latter query; you would need to have a function-based index on `TRUNC(CRTUPDDT)` instead.

Comment: I like the trunc idea that you and the others came up with.  Thanks!